# Rewriting a function

Tags: function, matlab, optimization

In the following code I would like to replace the definition of the function f

```
f=@(x)-x(1)*x(2)*x(3);
x0=[1 1 1];
lb=[0 0 0];

nonlincon=@constr;

x=fmincon(f,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[],nonlincon)

function [c,ceq] = constr(x)
c = [2*x(1)*x(2)+2*x(1)*x(3)+2*x(2)*x(3)-100 ; 1-x(1)*x(2)];
ceq = [];
end
```

I replaced it with

```
function erg = f(x)
erg = -x(1)*x(2)*x(3);
end
```

but unfortunatly it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The error message is "**Not enough input arguments.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet, `f` is a *function handle*, while in the second, its a *function*.

You can easily make it a function handle to be called by `fmincon` by calling `x=fmincon(@f,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[],nonlincon)`

Otherwise matlab is trying to call `f` and give its output to `fmincon`, which is not what you want to do.

Comment: @SB I am glad. Please accept the answer as valid for future readers to know